# How does one determine the absorption spectrum of water at audio wavelengths?

Tags: experimental-physics, acoustics, water, frequency

I know I can get the [visible absorption spectrum of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_absorption), but how does one go about getting and testing what the absorption spectrum is for a glass of water in the audio range of (0hz to 20000hz)? [I know nasa uses water to absorb sound](https://youtu.be/08aHEmuzMLI). How can I measure what the sound absorption spectrum is in a glass of water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why a "glass of water"  ?   If the sound is created outside the glass, you have to deal with two interfaces:   air-glass and glass-water.  If the sound is created inside the glass, are you simply looking for absorption/decay over an unbounded range of water?

Setting up experiments to measure the absorption would require at the least some high-quality hydrophones and an Olympic-sized swimming pool.  I don't recommend trying to reproduce what's been done by scientists with bitchin' gear.

That said, a simple LMWTFY finds  [this calculator](http://resource.npl.co.uk/acoustics/techguides/seaabsorption/) for seawater, and a [stack of formulae](http://resource.npl.co.uk/acoustics/techguides/soundpurewater/) for fresh water.

Comment: The second link is for calculating the speed of sound, not the absorption. Just to add a bit (given the vagueness of the question): if you're talking about  just how loud a sound is after travelling through water, you'd also need to take into account the inverse square law. And *in a glass*, you'd also have to deal with almost infinite reflections and their associated phase-cancellation, meaning that for any given position in the glass it'd be almost impossible to calculate the exact amplitude of a given frequency...